# How to make divs responsive using a custom wordpress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I have a custom wordpress theme that I am using, and I am editing one of my pages. I created 3 divs that basically should align horizontally in the center of the page. I figured out how to get everything aligned correctly, but I need it to be responsive. When I view the web page from a mobile device, the div's do not even appear fully on the screen and there is no scroll bar.

Please see the image as to how it should look. The three div's display the "Find Answers, Submit a Ticket, and Chat with an Agent" links:
[image]

Here is my code to create these divs:

```html
<center>
<div style="width: 900px;">

<a href="http://neawebservices.com/client/knowledgebase.php" target="_blank"><div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px; border-radius: 25px; border: 2px solid #007ebf; padding: 20px; height: 150px; text-align: center;">
<h3 class="priceplanhr">Find Answers</h3>
<img class="alignnone wp-image-980 size-full" src="http://neawebservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/64-X-64.png" alt="" width="66" height="44" />

</div></a>

<a href="https://neawebservices.com/client/submitticket.php" target="_blank"><div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px; border-radius: 25px; border: 2px solid #007ebf; padding: 20px; height: 150px; text-align: center;">
<h3 class="priceplanhr">Submit a Ticket</h3>
<img class="alignnone wp-image-980 size-full" src="http://neawebservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/128-X-128-3.png" alt="" width="66" height="44" />

</div></a>

<a href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())"><div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px; border-radius: 25px; border: 2px solid #007ebf; padding: 20px; height: 150px; text-align: center;">
<h3 class="priceplanhr">Chat with an Agent</h3>
<img class="alignnone wp-image-980 size-full" src="http://neawebservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/64-X-64-1.png" alt="" width="55" height="55" />

</div></a>
</div>
</center>
```

The theme uses external css but if I could get the same responsive effect using inline css, it would be great.

I would appreciate any help that I can get on this!!

Answer (score 2):

[CSS3 media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) are your friend here and no, they can't be done inline. It's generally best to stay away from using inline CSS anyways.

You could either build your own media queries (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)) or convert your theme to a CSS framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) (I personally prefer Foundation) to do them for you.